# How can I change a pandas stack into a single row dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I might need to extend my question...

I've got some kind of correlation matrix to work with (see example below, but think with a few thousand "Ref" columns.

```
              Ref_1          Ref_2
Base_1        0.021088       0.022260   
Base_2        0.022539       0.023792   
Base_3        0.026193       0.027648   
Base_4        0.027209       0.028721   
Base_5        0.000000       0.000000   
Base_6        0.000000       0.000000
```

I extracted the Top Values with following Code:

```
data = []

for row_index, row in similarity_df.iterrows():
    max_sim = row.max()
    max_sim_col = row.idxmax()
    data.append([row_index, max_sim_col, max_sim])

result_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Base', 'Ref', 'Score'])
```

All fine and working.

```
Base       Ref      Score
Base_1     Ref_2    0.022260
Base_2     Ref_2    0.023792
```

But I need to extract the "Top10" Ref values for each Base and have them readable within a dataframe or something like that.

```
Base       1_Ref    1_Score     2_Ref    2_Score     3_Ref   3_Score    etc...
Base_1     Ref_2    0.022260    Ref_1    0.021088    ...
Base_2     Ref_2    0.023792    Ref_1    0.022539    ...
```

I experimented with stacking, but did not get the expected result.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) , then reshape with a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
N = 10

out = (df
   .rename_axis(columns='Ref')
   .stack().sort_values(ascending=False)
   .reset_index(name='Score')
  # .groupby(level=0).head(N)
   .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby('level_0').cumcount()+1)
   .pivot(index='level_0', columns='n')
   .sort_index(level='n', axis=1)
   .rename_axis(index=None)
)

out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')
```

*NB. To limit the number of top values, uncomment the `.groupby(level=0).head(N)` line.*

Output:

```
        1_Ref   1_Score  2_Ref   2_Score
Base_1  Ref_2  0.022260  Ref_1  0.021088
Base_2  Ref_2  0.023792  Ref_1  0.022539
Base_3  Ref_2  0.027648  Ref_1  0.026193
Base_4  Ref_2  0.028721  Ref_1  0.027209
Base_5  Ref_1  0.000000  Ref_2  0.000000
Base_6  Ref_1  0.000000  Ref_2  0.000000
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Just the limit to the top 10 entries is not working. But just displaying the first 20 columns is no big issue.

Comment: @Marcus have you uncommented the `.groupby(level=0).head(N)`? How is it not working? you can also try `.query('n <= 10')` between the `assign` and `pivot` commands.